# Batch Script - Run as admin changes %username% parameter

Tags: command-line, batch-file

I have made a batch script, which contains various %username% fields in it. It needs admin privileges to run some commands, but when I do this all of the %username% fields that need admin to run get changed to the admin's username, instead of the user logged in. Is there anyway I can change this so these do not change?

Comment: pass the `%username%` as a parameter to the batch file, and use the parameter instead of `%username%` in the script https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26551/how-do-i-pass-command-line-parameters-to-a-batch-file

Comment: I've tried doing: set "user=%username%" but this still pulls in the admin username

Comment: how and where will this script be started? by an automated prozess on client computer? can you please elaborate on that a bit, otherwise i'm not sure if that's the best solution. please edit your question and include this information

Comment: Its a batch file which will be run manually logged in as the user. It needs to be run as admin but the user does not have admin on their machine.

Comment: and how are they passing credentials? do they know the admin account password?

Comment: A domain admin will be running the script, logged in as the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass `%username%` as a parameter to your Batch Script and use the parameter in your Batch Script instead of `%username%`

let's say your **script.bat** looks like this:

```
echo %username%
echo my name is %username%
pause
```

you can change it to this:

```
set SomeVar=%1
echo %SomeVar%
echo my name is %SomeVar%
pause
```

this will set the Variable `%SomeVar%` with the first argument (`%1`) that gets passed to your Script.

Save the script somewhere, then create a shortcut to the non-admin-user's desktop.

Then do the following (see screenshot below, sorry for german language)

1. Open the shortcut properties
2. add `%username%` to the target (this is the argument `%1`)
3. click on `advanced`
4. check `run as admin`
5. hit `ok`

when you double click the shortcut now and the user is not an admin, it will ask for credentials and run the script with your argument

[image]